# fade-out transition on bgcolor not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, js-scrollintoview

So I have a button that scrolls to a specific div and highlights it yellow for a second, but I can't make it fade out instead of just dissapearing. This is my code:

```js
function Go_to_file_creator() {
  var divElement = document.getElementsByClassName('form')[0];
  divElement.scrollIntoView();
  divElement.classList.add('highlighted');

  setTimeout(function() {
    divElement.classList.remove('highlighted');
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#toFileCreator {
  margin-right: 90vw;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Go_to_file_creator()" id="toFileCreator">
  <h1>File creator</h1>
</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your code need to be completed... [did you read SO recommendations about posting a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MisterJojo This is just part of my code, do you want me to includethe whole thing with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and stuff?

Comment: [did you read  carefully SO recommendations about posting a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there is the word **minimal**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code `fade-in` and `fade-out`, you need to have a forward and reverse transition. The original code only has a forward transition. So the `background color` change is instantaneous when you remove the class.

Add this line to your css:

```
.form {
  transition: background-color 3s;
}
```

Run the snippet to understand how it works.

**Snippet**

```js
function Go_to_file_creator() {
  var divElement = document.getElementsByClassName('form')[0];
  divElement.scrollIntoView();
  divElement.classList.add('highlighted');

  setTimeout(function() {
    divElement.classList.remove('highlighted');
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#toFileCreator {
  margin-right: 90vw;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.form {
  transition: background-color 3s;
}

.form.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <button onclick="Go_to_file_creator()" id="toFileCreator">
    <h1>File creator</h1>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked well